# focus issue in angularJS single page application in mobile talk back

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, focus, accessibility

I have been developing a single page application in angularJS. I had to test the application for 'talk back' feature in the mobile accessibility. While I was testing the app for page navigation, if I double tap on a button or a link, the focus would come over that button or link and the page navigation(since single page application, only view changes) happens, but the focus remains at the same position. It is not getting refreshed in the new page. As a result, the talk back feature is not reading out the new page title. Why this happens? If this can be resolved using javascript or angularJS, please specify the steps.